# How to remove http headers from curl response?

Tags: bash, curl

How to remove HTTP headers from curl response in bash?
I am getting this header values on every response how can I remove them? or not receive them?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 20 Jun 2015 11:43:15 GMT
Content-Length: 1837
```

Comment: curl only shows headers with -I please add the exact command you are using.

Comment: curl -i -u $authentication -H $content_type --digest -X POST $url --data $parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read on the curl [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

> -i, --include
>
> (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header includes things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and more...

Your command should be:

```
curl -u $authentication -H $content_type --digest -X POST $url --data $parameters
```